# After QPixmap::grabWindow application frozen

Tags: c++, qt, screenshot, desktop, qpixmap

After I use this  function

```
QPixmap::grabWindow(QApplication::desktop()->winId(),50,100,950,700);
```

my application is frozen and I am not able to use other button in my application.
Why is that so?

Comment: Does this work:     QPixmap desktop = QPixmap::grabWindow(QApplication::desktop()->winId());

Comment: To the first point: The Problem stays the same when using QPixmap::grabWindow(QApplication::desktop()->winId()); And I am using Mac.

Comment: Which rendering engine are you using? Which version of Qt? Personally I have found bugs in the Qt Mac graphics engine, which Qt are happy to fix if they can be tracked down.

Comment: To back up my last claim: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/merge_requests/1332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with my Qt installation (4.8 on OS X 10.6.8). Make sure you have a instance of QApplication before calling anything in QtGUI.